# Grails/SpringSecurity : how to create user without being identified previously?

Tags: grails, spring-security

I'm trying to create a Twitter-like app with Grails and SpringSecurity plugin, and what I want to do is to allow potential users to create an account from the login page (`auth.gsp` in SpringSecurityCore).

On this page I have a link to my `UserTwitter`'s controller's `create` method. It calls the usual `create.gsp` page. And the problem : when I try to create a new account, it works when I'm previously logged in with another account, but doesn't if I'm not. What should I do ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

May be your action is secured by Spring Security Service by using annotation or URL mapping in config. If this is the case then free your action from Spring Security Service. See this  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18827054/how-to-bypass-spring-security-login-check-in-grails/18827184#18827184) to free your action from Spring Security Service.